# UNC mounting from web application

Tags: mount, server-message-block, arch-linux, unc

I've got a problem with long-term UNC mounts from my web application cluster (Arch Linux to various Windows versions) timing out so am looking into short-term (on demand) mount/unmount cycles via scripting - the obvious problem is permissions. I really don't want to hand over root/sudo to the web application. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a (CIFS) mount in /etc/fstab with the users option, nobody will need root to mount it.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that - the only issue is the credentials file, but that's a much easier pill to swallow.